# How to achieve associative law in django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have three objects for a model A, B, C
A is related to B
and B is related to C
How can I achieve relation from A to C in django?

```
class Product(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
similar_product = models.ManyToManyField('self')
```

Suppose I create an object A of model Product and another object B for the same model. and for B, I add A as the similar_product. That will create the relation 
B -> A and A -> B as well.
Now I add another product with name C and its similar product is A.
as A is related to B, I want to assign B as similar product to C also.(De morgan's law)

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Can you please add your three models in quesion?

Comment: Sorry i guess i wasn't clear. I dont have 3 models. I have edited my question with my model. All the objects belong to this model.

Comment: I am not getting you properly, can you please add more details like actually what is your desired output.

Comment: Is my question clear with this edit?

Answer (score 2):

I assume your model like that:

```
class C(models.Model):
    #some fields

class B(models.Model):
    c = models.ForeignKey(C)

class A(models.Model):
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)
```

If you have a object you can access `a.b.c` to c easily.

On your queries you can use `__` operator:

```
A.objects.filter(b__c=#your c object)
```

Comment: I have edited my question. I dont have 3 models.  Its a many to many relation to self.

Answer (score 0):

So let's assume you have a given `Product` and want to **test** whether another given `Product` is *similar* to the first one:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    similar_products = models.ManyToManyField('self')
    def is_similar(self, other):
        if other in self.similar_products.all():
            return True
        else:
            # recursively call is_similar()
            return any(similar.is_similar(other) for similar in self.similar_products.all())
```

That doesn't require you to add the relationships when they are created. So now you can do `a.is_similar(b)` to check if `a` and `b` are related and this would return `True` if `a` <=> `c` <=> `d` <=> `b`.

If you prefer to explicitly add all the relationships when a <=> c is created, use a [signal handler](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/signals/#m2m-changed) for `m2m_changed`:

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Product):
def add_connections(sender, instance, action, **kwargs):
    # instance is a
    # pk_set contains the pk of c
    if action == 'post_add':
        for similar in instance.similar_products.all():
            # similar is b for example (existing relationship with a)
             similar.similar_products.add(Product.objects.filter(pk__in=pk_set))
```

*Note: I changed your field `similar_products` to be plural as that is what it should be in a m2m relationship.*